# How come the Up-casting for c is redundant?

Tags: java, dynamic, casting, binding

I am trying to figure out why the casting is redundant(thats the warning I get) in the end whats printed is "C".

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    C c = new C();
    B b1 = (B) c;
    b1.f();
    }
}

class A{
    void f(){
    System.out.println("A");
   }
}

class B extends A{

}

class C extends B{
    void f(){
    System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

Comment: I compiled and ran your class without any error. Where are you seeing the warning? What version of Java?

Answer (score 2):

`C extends B` means that `C` is a `B`. And you do not need to cast `C` to `B`, because it IS a `B`.

So upcast (C to B) is always redundant. The only case when you would need cast is downcast (B to C):

```
B b = new C();
C c = (C) b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Class c extends class B. So any C object is also a B object because of inheritance. So you do not need to explicitly cast '(B)' before c.